# Complex series convergence domain

Tags: complex-analysis

There was a small but very crucial mistake in the series, but now it is fixed.

Find the domain of absolute convergence for:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{(n!)(iz+1)^n} {n^3+ 3 \sqrt {n}} $$

which test should be used in this case?

I tried the ratio test, but the terms did not cancel out (some did):

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)!(iz+1)^{n+1}} {(n+1)^3 + 3 \sqrt {n+1}} \frac {n^3+ 3 \sqrt {n}} {(n!)(iz+1)^n} $

$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)(iz+1)} {(n+1)^3 + 3 \sqrt {n+1}} \frac {n^3+ 3 \sqrt {n}} {1} $

I am kind of stuck at this point. Any help to pass this point is appreciated.

Comment: Is there anywhere the terms decrease to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: None because raising $\infty$ to any power gives $\infty$

Comment: Almost.  $z = \dfrac{-1}{\mathrm{i}}$ "decreases" to zero quite rapidly...

Comment: Remember to take absolute values when using the ratio test. Also, what did you find difficult in taking the limit?

Comment: I need more terms to cancel out so that I can set the remainder of the terms < 1 for the convergence condition to be true which is necessary to find the domain of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the
$n!$ in the numerator,
the sum diverges
wherever
$(iz+1) \ne 0$.

Therefore,
the domain of convergence
is the point
$z = -1/i = i$.